# Question about Modifying Case Chatter Post Name Options

Tags: community, chatter, administration, chatter-feed

As the Salesforce Admin for our company, I have a couple of questions regarding the Chatter post settings for cases.

Can I modify the two name options, "My Company Only" and "All with Access," for Case Chatter posts? Specifically, I would like to rename "My Company Only" to something else that better suits our organization.

Additionally, is it possible to add more options for Chatter post visibility, besides just "My Company Only" and "All with Access"?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to upvote for this limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfZDUAZ/change-default-audience-for-chatter).  This is salesforce standard functionality and you cannot customize or make any changes.